# Rails - Checkbox not working with Remember Me for Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, authlogic

So I have been using Authlogic to allow user account creation and authentication. I have most of the features I want for the user but I am currently running into trouble regarding the "remember_me" function.

I have a check box to indicate whether the user wants to be remembered after the closed the browser or not. However, no matter what, even if I check the box or not, the remember me is set to false. When the user_session is created, I can see the value for "remember_me" being correct based on the state of the check box. Despite that, when I print out the value of "remember_me" to the console, it is false no matter whether the checkbox was checked or not.

The remember_me feature works as intended when I force the value to be true using the following:

```
@user_session.remember_me = true
```

and place that within the UserSession controller. The [two](https://github.com/bodrovis/Sitepoint-source/tree/master/Authentication_with_AuthLogic) [examples](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) I used both utilize check boxes to determine the value for the field and I believed I followed them correctly so I do not know why my check boxes are not setting the "remember_me" field appropriately. The one problem I think might be happening is that the check box is saving the value to another field called "remember_me" which is why the actual field is always false.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or have any advice on how to do so? Thanks!

User Sessions Controller:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(user_session_params)
    #@user_session.remember_me = true
    #puts(@user_session.remember_me)
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:success] = 'Welcome back'
      redirect_to home_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Failed to log in'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'Goodbye'
    #redirect_to root_path - Should redirect somewhere after signout
  end

  private

  def user_session_params
    params.require(:user_session).permit(:email,:password,:remember_me)
  end

end
```

User Session "new.html.erb"

```
<div class="loginContainer" align="center">

  <h1 align="center"><b>Log In</b></h1>

  <%= form_for @user_session do |u| %>
      <div class="container">

        <%= render 'shared/errors', object:@user_session %>

        <label><b>Email</b></label>
        <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email Address' %>
        <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required> -->

        <br>
        <label>
          <b>Password</b>
        </label>
        <%= u.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>
        <!--<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required> -->

        <br>

        <%= u.label 'Remember me' %>
        <%= u.check_box :remember_me %>

        <%= u.submit 'Login', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <!-- <button type="submit">Login</button> -->


      </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="container" style="background-color:#D3D3D3">
    <%= link_to 'Forgot your password?', new_password_reset_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

User Session Model

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base


    def to_key
      new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
    end

  end
```

User Session Request Parameters (with checkbox checked):

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"fake@gmail.com", "password"=>"password1", "remember_me"=>"1"} permitted: true>
```

Comment: Can you provide the request params for the create action?

Comment: @fbelanger Apologies for the late reply. I added the request parameters as you wanted, I don't know if I did it right but I used "puts user_session_params.inspect" in the User Session Controller

Comment: Nice! So I haven't use AuthLogic and your code looks good. However, try sending the same param value in the Rails console `@user_sessions.remember_me = '1'` and see if that is the issue. That's the only thing that could be off IMO. Btw, `puts params` would of been fine too!

Comment: @fbelanger What are the steps to doing that? I'm new to rails so I apologize. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the exact data that is sent to your action.

```
puts params
=> {user_session: {..., remember_me: "1"}}
```

Then try the operation in console to see if the checkbox data is being interpreted as `true`, I suspect this is the issue.

```
rails c
params = {..., remember_me: "1"}
session = UserSession.new(params)
session.remember_me?
=> false # if "1" is not setting this to true
=> true # if "1" is setting this true
```

If this is the issue you need the data to be a Ruby `true` boolean.

```
def user_session_params
  if params[:user_session][:remember_me].present? # not nil or ""
   params[:user_session][:remember_me] = true
  end
  params.require(...).permit(...)
end
```

Though I have this feeling that Rails is smart enough to handle this boolean column as presence based.

Comment: Alright I tried the following and when I typed in `session.remember_me?`, it returned true. I honestly do not know why it returns false when I print out the value with `puts @user_session.remember_me?`. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: One thing you could do is use `byebug` to step through your controller.

Add `byebug` below the first line and check the values, then in the `byebug` console, do `@user_session.save` as your controller would do and then check `.valid?`, `.errors?`, `.remember_me?`. It's really strange, your code looks fine!